# Как узнать какой метод больше загружает процессор?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, производительность

Есть несколько реализаций `MD5`, к примеру. Узнать, какой метод из них выполняется быстрее - не проблема. Как корректно узнать какой из этих методов дает большую нагрузку на процессор?

Comment: md5 все операции делает исключительно на процессоре, следовательно то что дольше выполняется то и сильнее грузит процессор. вернее любой из этих методов гарантированно грузит ядро на 100% просто на разное время

Comment: @Mike, т.е. получается, то что продолжительнее занимает процессорное время - то и дает большую нагрузку на процессор?

Comment: @Mike очевидно. Если вам нужны отчеты о производительности, то просто воспользуйтесь любым профайлером. Например https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, ну использовать сторонние профайлеры в таком простом деле, к тому же не бюджетные - черезчур.

Comment: В студии есть встроенный профилировщик

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм, точно. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, или можно воспользоваться [этой библиотекой](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Comment: @User101057 Нагрузка на процессор в принципе меряется во времени его полезной работы (когда он не переведен в состояние останова операционной системой из за отсутствия работы). с другой стороны мереть просто время работы можно только если в этом время система больше ничем не занята, ведь если желающих получить процессор потоков более чем ядер, то ОС будет делить время порциями между ними

Comment: @Mike мне кажется всякие мерилки производительности (если это не самопальный StopWatch) должны об этом всем заботиться сами из коробки

Answer (score 1):

Для получения процессорного времени, затраченного на выполнение однопоточного метода, необходимо вычесть значения *ProcessThread.TotalProcessorTime* после и до выполнения метода. Соответственно, загрузку процессора (среднюю), создаваемую в ходе его выполнения, можно найти, разделив полученное значение на `Environment.ProcessorCount * ВремяВыполнения`. Для повышения точности расчетов произвести измерение несколько раз и найти среднее. Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{    
    class Program
    {
        /* Измеряемый метод */
        public static Int64 DoSomething(Int64 x)
        {
            Int64 res = 1; 
            for (Int64 i = 1; i <= x; i++) res += i;
            return res;
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        const int N = 50; //число итераций

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(5000000).ToString()); //прогрев

            Int64 sum=0;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            var id = GetCurrentThreadId();//получаем ID текущего потока

            Process pr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            ProcessThread thread = null;

            //находим объект ProcessThread для текущего потока
            foreach (ProcessThread th in pr.Threads)
            {
                if (th.Id == (int)id) thread = th;
            }
            if (thread == null) { Console.WriteLine("ProcessThread not found"); return; }

            sw.Start();//начало измерений
            var before = thread.TotalProcessorTime.Ticks;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                sum += DoSomething(50000000);//вызов измерямого метода                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
            var after = thread.TotalProcessorTime.Ticks;
            sw.Stop();//конец измерений            

            double processor_time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(after - before).TotalMilliseconds / N;
            double total_time = (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) / (double)N;
            double usage = (processor_time) / (Environment.ProcessorCount * total_time) * 100.0;

            Console.WriteLine("Processor time:" + Math.Round(processor_time,2).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Total time:" + total_time.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Usage %:" + Math.Round(usage,1).ToString());            

        }
    }
}
```

Если *DoSomething* выполняет только голые вычисления, без обращения к вводу/выводу или ожидания событий, значение загрузки будет близко к `100% / Environment.ProcessorCount`. Если он содержит вызов *Thread.Sleep*, загрузка будет близка к нулю. Все остальное - что-то посередине.

Если метод многопоточный, нужно либо суммировать по всем задействованным потокам, либо просто брать *Process.TotalProcessorTime* для грубого приближения (в предположении, что ничего другого в данный момент в процессе не происходит).

Comment: А не проще будет, вместо велосипединга, взять BenchmarkDotNet, и сравнить два метода?